# Why is git submodule giving a syntax error?

Tags: python

```
git submodule add git://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python/ evernote
git submodule init
git submodule update

dev_token = "#DevTokenHere"
client = EvernoteClient(token=dev_token)
userStore = client.get_user_store()
user = userStore.getUser()
print(user.username)
```

I get a syntax error from the submodule part and  I'm not sure why

Comment: Is this supposed to be Python code? Because `git submodule ...` looks like shell code and would result in a SyntaxError in Python, while the second part of your code looks like Python code.

Comment: Python doesn't allow using console commands as simple as that

Comment: Those first 3 lines aren't Python code, they're console commands; I really hope you're not just sticking those in a Python file and expecting it to work.